# Resistor connections

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, electrical-resistance

I can't figure out what kind of connection it would be if i put resistors like this[image]

Can someone please explain how they are connected, like is R1 and R2 in series and R4 and R5 in series and then I make a parallel of R12 and R45 and R3?

And what if I replaced R3 with a capacitor would it be connected in parallel with these resistors so I could get the charge on the capacitor by doing $q = C * U$

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This cannot be reduced to any simple series-parallel combination and you need to use Kirchoff's laws to find the current flowing in the branches. A special case of this circuit which is easy to handle is the wheatstone bridge.