# Same current flowing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, symmetry, electrical-resistance

In the following circuit how can we say that the current flowing through both the $4\Omega$ would be same .

[image: resistors]

I know it would be same if in middle the $\frac{2}{3}\Omega$ is not there but here it is here . And for having same current flowing the potential difference should be equal between both the $4\Omega$ resistance

Comment: I don't think this deserves a close vote.  This *looks* like a homework problem, but it's really about a concept.   I suggest that you consider how the mirror-image circuit (left/right) would behave.

Comment: @garyp can you please explain me more about that

Comment: I'm trying not to.   :)   Let's assume the opposite, and see if that leads to a contradiction.  Assume that the current in the left $4 \Omega$ resistor is greater than the one on the right.  Now consider the currents in the  mirror-image circuit.  Think about that for a while.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry.

At the left hand node the current can go through either the  $2\Omega$ or the  $4\Omega$ resistor and then the rest of the circuit, $\frac{2}{3}\Omega$,  $2\Omega$ and $4\Omega$.

At the right hand node the situation is exactly similar in that the current comes from an identically arranged $\frac{2}{3}\Omega$, $2\Omega$ and $4\Omega$, and then passes through either a $2\Omega$ or $4\Omega$ resistor.

The same logic can be applied to the $2\Omega$ resistors.

Comment: Come on!  Posting the solution?  Well ... I guess I argued earlier that this is not a homework problem, so I reap what I sew.   But we missed an opportunity to get the OP to figure it out for him/herself.

Comment: It means if instead of 2/3 ohm resistance we have any resistance then also the current is same

Comment: @koolman  That is a good way of thinking about the problem and so if it can be any value of resistance then substituting $0 \; \Omega$ or $\infty \; \Omega$ for $\frac 2 3 \; \Omega$ immediately shows the equality of the currents.

Comment: But what would happen if instead of 2/3 ohm we place a battery

Comment: @Farcher but as according to jim28 now it is asymmetry

Comment: If you solve for a battery or battery and resistor instead of the 2/3 ohm resistor you will find the currents through the 4 ohm resistors are the same.

Comment: OK, yes I agree, will remove the comment.