# Circuit, Wye-Delta transformation(?)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm new to circuit analysis and I'm stuck on this question. My question is: What could I do, or what steps should I take to solve this kind of circuit?

> [image]

What the question asks is basically the current going through resistor $R_2$, using nodal current analysis just gives me a bunch of equations and I can't use voltage analysis, finally I tried to do the equivalent resistance using the Wye-Delta transformation of the circuit and find that overall node is subject to a voltage of $45 \;\text{V}$ but what do I do with that?

Comment: Wye vs delta is usually with respect to 3 phase ac…

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.