# Equivalent Resistance in arbitrary situation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance

> Find the equivalent resistance between points A and B.
>
> [image: 1]

I tried to connect a battery of emf $E$, drew a current $I$ from it, and formed equations and variables but was unable to solve them. Please tell me if I'm thinking in the right direction or there's some trick here.
Furthermore, if a circuit has no pattern like Wheatstone's bridge, as in our case, then what method is used to find the equivalent resistance in general?

Comment: Do you know about [delta-Y conversions](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/delta-y-and-y-conversions/)?

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with solving the equations not with the physics of the problem. You should have a set of linear, algebraic equations. Why were you unable to solve them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451

Comment: The most general method is to use [Kirchhoff's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws). In addition, if there are multiple batteries, you just need to consider them one at a time, and treat their internal resistance (if any) as an ordinary resistor. Then this problem reduces to solving a system of $N$ linear equations, or equivalently, finding the inverse of a $N \times N$ matrix. By the way, this is the working principle of basic circuit analysis software.