# Equivalent Resistance of the resistance network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

For the below circuit, I'm tasked to find the equivalent resistance. My teacher used Kirchhoff's law to determine the resistance to be R_eq =  7R/5. However I get a different result using a different method.

[image]

My method:

[image]

I have assumed a current 'i' flows through the network initially. What mistake did I do using this method?

Note: The red colour indicates the current and the blue colour indicates the potential drop across each element

Comment: You splitting the currents formulae rely on the assumption that the pd across the vertical $R$ is zero which is not necessarily the case.  Put another way, the two horizontal resistors on the left hand side are not in parallel.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.