Find the total resistance and explain how
Circuit Diagram 



How are we supposed to find the resistance
What I tried:
The middle one remains isolated 
However, the upper ones and lower ones add up
So, there are 2 resistors of 2ohms and one resistor of 1ohm, all three in parallel
Hence, R(equivalent) would be:
$$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}   $$
$$ \frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} $$
This gives R(equivalent) as a $\frac{1}{2}$, which is not correct
 So, how am I supposed to do it.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.

This is one of those horrible textbook questions designed to confuse students.
The middle-most resistor is supposed to be rotated. Then you can straighten and align all the other resistors so show a very symmetric version of it. Then you will realise that it is basically very easy to solve. But it requires that you first be able to redraw this circuit to be in that symmetric and obviously simple form, or else you cannot hope to see why the answer is simple.

so , after this , my answer is coming 6/5. Is it correct?

No. Try this approach... Suppose that the middle of the three resistors in the vertical line of resistors were removed. What then would be the potential difference between the points to which it had been connected? [You now have two independent potential dividers.] So how much current would there be through any resistor (re)connected between those points? That makes things much simpler!

Could you please give me a proper answer (I am very new to this so I am unable to understand) @PhilipWood

No, sorry; this site doesn't provide answers to homework or homework-like questions. But I'm happy to try and help you sort out the relevant concepts. First step: were you able to answer my question: "What then would be the potential difference between the points to which it had been connected?"?

[
ps://i.sstatic.net/rUmIyXfk.jpg

Easy if you recognise it as a Wheatstone bridge?
