How to solve this circuit for total resistance?

I am unable to figure out which two are connected in parallel. The initial current splits at 4 and 5 ohm resistors. But if I consider those two parallel the current exiting 4 and 3 goes into 2. Then they are in parallel. 1 and 3 seem to be in parallel but 3 and 4 are also in parallel. How to solve this?

Just use Kirchhoff's laws.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22252/2451 and links therein.

I think the following would help you to organize the circuit. I don't know if this is the ideal way to solve this because I am just a high school student and my teacher taught me this way and I thought it would be easier to solve these type of questions with this thing.
Let the junction of resistances having resistance $5~\Omega, 3~\Omega $ and $1~\Omega$ be X, similarly, the junction of resistances having resistance $4~\Omega, 3~\Omega $ and $2~\Omega$ be Y.
So, the circuit would look something like this:

And then you can name other points whose potential is same. Like this:

So, now you can clearly see which resistance is between which points.
Now, you can reorganize the circuit like this:

Now, I think the circuit is pretty much easy to solve, you can use Kirchhoff's Laws to find the effective resistance.
Again Disclaimer: I don't know if this is the ideal way to solve these kind of problems. I am just reorganizing the circuit using the way taught by my teacher.
Hope this helps.

Actually, this bending of wires doesn't make it clearer IMO (at least if you're gonna use Kirchhoff's laws): you still have two obvious loops and four obvious junctions as you did initially. So you can formulate a consistent set of six equations for six unknown currents. Then by Ohm's law you get the effective resistance.

@Ruslan Yeah, that method can also be used. But, for me, I find this method of bending loops and then applying Kirchhoff's Laws more easier than six equations. So, I thought the question asker might also like it. Thanks for pointing that out.

How do you apply Kirchhoff's laws without solving equations?

@Ruslan I don't know the original names of methods (Sorry for that). I think this can be solved using something called Delta-Star Transformation (I don't know what it is called, but I think this is what it is called). Yeah, you're correct, Kirchhoff's laws would not give an answer.

Oh, I see, nice shortcut. You could show this process more explicitly like in this image.
